# Makefile: Get filename component of the most recently updated file

Tags: makefile

Can I  reference the **filename component** of the last updated file, in a list of file. Not the **file extension component**? How could one go about this?

I have a Makefile which lists a number of files. E.g.:

```
FILES= file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

If I could get the most recently updated file in `FILES` I would be able to have a Makefile target it. For example:

```
viewThatFile: open $(LAST_TOUCHED_FILE_IN_FILES).html
```

This would be awesome!

*I am using OSX btw.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LATEST := $(basename $(shell ls -1t $(FILES) | head -1))
```